# Extract numbers from string (Regex C++)

Tags: c++, regex, expression

let's say i hve a string `S = "1 this is a number=200; Val+54 4class find57"`

i want to use `Regex` to extract only this numbers:

```
   num[1] = 1
   num[2] = 200
   num[3] = 54
```

and not the 4 in "4class" or 57 in "find57" which means only numbers that are surrounded by `Operators` or `space`.
i tried this code but no results:

```
std::string str = "1 this is a number=200; Val+54 4class find57";
 boost::regex re("(\\s|\\-|\\*|\\+|\\/|\\=|\\;|\n|$)([0-9]+)(\\s|\\-|\\*|\\+|\\/|\\;|\n|$)");
 boost::sregex_iterator m1(str.begin(), str.end(), re);
 boost::sregex_iterator m2;
 for (; m1 != m2; ++m1) {

    advm1->Lines->Append((*m1)[1].str().c_str());

                        }
```

by the way i'am using `c++ Builder XE6.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use word boundaries. `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character.

```
\b\d+\b
```

OR

```
\b[0-9]+\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/30)

Escape the backslash one more time if necessary like `\\b\\d+\\b` or `\\b[0-9]+\\b`

Comment: how would you also support floating point numbers ?

Comment: `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b`