# C++: Extracting integers from string object

Tags: c++

I have something like:

```
string s = "Max of 3 and 5";
```

or

```
string s = "9 divided by -3";
```

and I need to display the result of the expression.

But, how do I extract the operands from the string. 
In Java, I can but I'm not sure in C++.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400131/extract-numbers-from-string-regex-c

Comment: But, I don't want to use reg exps

Comment: @Boyyett Well, there are various methods available, e.g. [`stoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Answer (score 0):

why not use sscanf?

```
int a{};

int b{};

std::sscanf("max of 3 and 5", "max of %d and %d", &a, &b);
```