# find average salaries from file in c++

Tags: c++, string, file, average

I need to find average salary from employees of file

```
   John Harris $50000.00
   Lisa Smith $75000.00
   Adam Johnson $68500.00
   Sheila Smith $150000.00
   Tristen Major $75800.00
   Yannic Lennart $58000.00
   Lorena Emil $43000.00
   Tereza Santeri $48000.00
```

How can I access the salaries of the employees so that i can find the average? I have managed to get each line of a file into a string but I dont know how to access the salaries of each employee
my code is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>

#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream in;
    in.open("HW6Prob2.txt");

    if(in.fail())
    {
        cout<<"ERROR: File could not open."<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    string word[8];

    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        getline(in,word[i]);    //get line string
        out<<word[i]<<endl;
    }
    string a=word[0];
    string b=word[1];
    string d=word[3];
    string e=word[4];
    string f=word[5];
    string g=word[6];
    string h=word[7];
    cout<<a[13]<<endl;
    string sum=
    cout<<sum<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to use `regex` in c++11. It is just suitable for your question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400131/extract-numbers-from-string-regex-c    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627440/regex-c-extract-substring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you keep adding the average while you read the lines, so you just iterate once through the salaries list.

```
int i = 0; 
float avg_salary = 0;
string line;
// get the sum while you read the lines
while(getline(in, line)) {
    // find the first salary digit position (just after the $ sign)
    int salaryStartPos = line.find('$') + 1;
    // Convert the salary string to a float with the atof method
    avg_salary += atof(line.substr(salaryStartPos, line.size()-1)
    ++i;
}
// Finally calculate the average
avg_salary = avg_salary / i;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help. I got it to work!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a school assignment, so I'll give you some tips on how to approach the challenge with pseudo-code:

```
sum = 0
numberOfPersons = 0
for each line in "HW6Prob2.txt"
  pos = find position of $
  salary = cut the string from pos and parse as double

  sum = sum + salary
  numberOfPersons = numberOfPersons + 1
loop

average = sum / numberOfPersons
```

I hope you'll find this helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [stof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stof/) function to get the float value from the string. All you need is to figure out the starting point of the float. In your case, you can use `position of $ + 1` as the starting point. Use [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) function for that.

Answer (score 0):

First you should iterate through the file lines (until end) to read all the data:

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(file, line))
{
  // tokenize to get the last item and store it
}
```

If you have your file structure strictly defined as presented: [first_name] [last_name] $[salary] you can read each salary entry like:

```
const string salaryText = line.substr(line.find_last_of('$') + 1);
```

The extracted salary text should be converted to a number and either stored in a `vector<float>` or aggregated for each line. This depends on whether you also need to access particular salaries at some point. If you'd go with the vector option you could write smth like:

```
salaryList.push_back(std::stof(salaryText));
```

Afterwards you can calculate mean salary with:

```
const double salarySum = std::accumulate(salaryList.begin(), salaryList.end(), 0.0);
const double salaryMean = salarySum / salaryList.size();
```

The advantage of having the salary list is that you can further calculate other statistics, not only the mean value.