# How to calculate the average?

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I was asked to calculate the average of marks for 10 students.
First, I was able to read and retrieve the data from data.txt file which looks like this:

> No.       Name        Test1           Test2           Test3
>
> 1     Ahmad       58          97          83
>
> 2     Dollah      78          76          70
>
> 3     Ramesh      85          75          84
>
> 4     Maimunah    87          45          74
>
> 5     Robert      74          68          97
>
> 6     Kumar       77          73          45
>
> 7     Intan       56          23          27
>
> 8     Ping        74          58          18
>
> 9     Idayu       47          98          95
>
> 10        Roslan      79          98          78

Then I have to calculate the average for each student and determine the grades.

Here are what I've done so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    ifstream inFile1;
    string temp;
    int line=0;

    inFile1.open("data.txt");
    if(inFile1.fail())
    {
        cout << "File cannot be opened" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    while(getline(inFile1, temp))
    {
        line++;
    }
    inFile1.close();

    return 0;
}
```

This program should at least consists two prototype function: average() and grade().
This is where I got stuck.

Comment: Please don't post link to images containing code, copy/paste your code directly into your question using the Code Sample tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the answers here: [find average salaries from file in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161547/find-average-salaries-from-file-in-c/41161968#41161968).

Basically when you iterate through the file lines you should split the `temp` string into tokens you are interested in. How? An option would be to use `getline` with the delimeter `' '` or look into the `std::noskipws` stream manipulator or simply use `operator>>` to read from the file - depends on the details of your requirements.

If I correctly understand your case, I'd go with the `operator>>` to get the name of the student and then read using `getline(inFile, gradesText)` to read until end of line to get all grades for the current student.

Then I'd use a separate function to split the strings into a vector of grades. How to do the splitting you can check in [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c). This way you could prepare a function like `vector<int> split(const string& line, char delim = ' ')`. Within the implementation you should probably use `std::stoi` for the string-to-int conversion.

Afterwards, when you already have a proper collection you can calculate the mean from it with:

```
const double sum = std::accumulate(grades.begin(), grades.end(), 0.0);
const double gradesMean = sum / grades.size();
```